# Image is not loading while using React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a site using react.js and I was able to render the picture but I am not able to view the picture. I need some help. I am creating a website for a client. I am trying to render the image from Header.jsx. The picture is saved in public/Images/Img1.jpg. I have a component folder which as App.jsx, CreateArea.jsx, Header.jsx, Footer.jsx and Navbar.jsx.

[Error with pic

```js
import React from "react";
import NavbarHeader from "./Navbar";



function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
    <NavbarHeader
    />
    <h1>SyncTech Solutions- Take your business beyond the four walls. </h1>
    <img src = "/Images/Img1.jpg"></img>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zw28.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Images/Img1.jpg`} />
```

for using images from public folder.

`process.env.PUBLIC_URL` will store your public url... The one which you access with `%PUBLIC_URL%` in the `index.html` file.

You could use `require` or `import` syntax if your image was inside `src` folder since it would be processed by webpack then.

But `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` seems to be the correct option in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<img>` tag with

```
<Image source={require('./Images/Img1.jpg')} />
```

Comment: I tried the code and it is giving an error: Line 13:6:  'Image' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef. I tried to import the image using: import Img1 from "/Images/Img1.jpg". Still there is an error